# Balance connection according to the number of users in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have database in SQL Server

I have created 5 users in my database.

```
User1
User2
User3
User4
User5
```

My application is connected by 5 connection strings to this database.

I want that if 1000 users connect to my database through application at one time then SQL Server automatically divide the users among 5 users of SQL Server.

Like

- 200 Users connecting to SQL Server using `User1`
- 200 Users connecting to SQL Server using `User2`

and so on...

How could U achieve this in SQL Server?

Comment: What is the idea or reason behind this?? Typically, you have to define the user to use in your **connection string** and it cannot be handled dynamically by SQL Server. ...

Comment: reason behind this to divide load on each user of sql server because each user of sql server have 1 connection string in web application

Comment: Just by using different users, you aren't dividing load at all - it's still all on the same server ...

Comment: What's the actual problem you're trying to solve here?

Comment: If you *truly* must distribute load - then you need a SQL Server **cluster** with multiple **machines** - not just multiple SQL Server user accounts..... Why do you feel the need to distribute the load? Maybe your database design and/or indexing just isn't up to the challenge.... what **exactly** is the problem you're up against?